# Running python3 with debug set to OFF with -O

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, command-line-arguments

If I run `python3 -O` on bash like:

```
(base) [xyx@xyz python_utils]$ python3 -O                                                                                                                Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 28 2018, 11:00:11) [GCC 6.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if __debug__:print("hello")
...
>>> exit()
```

I see that the `__debug__` variable is set to `0`, because the `print("hello") call isn't reached. But if I write the same above line in a python file and run it in the usual way like

```sh
$ cat debugprint.py
if __debug__:print("hello")
$ python3 debugprint.py -O
hello
```

Then we see the text `"hello"` which means `__debug__` is still true.
Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `-O` to Python, not to your script. You do so by putting the switch *before* your script file on the command-line:

```sh
python3 -O debugprint.py
#       ^^    ^^          ^^ any script command-line args go here.
#        |      \ scriptname
# arguments to Python itself
```

any command-line arguments that follow the script name are instead *passed to the script* in the `sys.argv` list:

```sh
$ cat debugargs.py
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
print(__debug__)
$ python3 debugargs.py -O
['-O']
True
python3 -O /tmp/test.py -O
['-O']
False
```

Alternatively, you can also set the [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) to a non-empty value:

```sh
$ export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1
python3 /tmp/test.py  # no command-line switches
[]
False
```

Comment: Sorry! I agree with your point. I saw people starting to downvote the question and so thought of deleting it!

Comment: Your question is valid enough. I've edited it to make it a bit clearer, so hopefully it'll garner upvotes too, over time.